# What is the electron configuration of platinum?

Tags: electronic-configuration, reference-request

Some textbooks write the electron configuration for platinum (Pt) as $\ce{[Xe] 4f^14 5d^9 6s^1}$. However, some also write it as $\ce{[Xe] 4f^14 5d^8 6s^2}$. Which is correct?

I hope someone can help me with an authoritative source.

Comment: Please, learn to use better grammar when writing your text. Start sentences with a capital letter. You don't need to put so many spaces between each word.

Comment: See Madelung rule exception: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35086/exceptions-to-the-madelung-rule-for-electronic-configurations

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/anomalous-electronic-configuration-of-platinum

Answer (score 4):

The [NIST Atomic Spectra Database](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/ie.pl?spectra=Pt&units=1&at_num_out=on&el_name_out=on&seq_out=on&shells_out=on&level_out=on&e_out=0&unc_out=on&biblio=on),<sup>[1]</sup> which is as authoritative as it gets, shows that $\ce{5d^9 6s^1}$ is the correct ground-state electronic configuration for platinum.

Various inorganic textbooks also say the same. Wikipedia cites [Meissler and Tarr](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inorganic-Chemistry-Gary-L-Miessler/dp/0321811054) for this table: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Other_exceptions_to_Madelung's_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Other_exceptions_to_Madelung%27s_rule)

1. Kramida, A., Ralchenko, Yu., Reader, J., and NIST ASD Team (2020). *NIST Atomic Spectra Database* (ver. 5.8), [Online]. Available: https://physics.nist.gov/asd [2021, January 6]. National Institute of Standards and Technology, Gaithersburg, MD. DOI: https://doi.org/10.18434/T4W30F